# go-ethereum ethclient - cannot get event logs data

Tags: go-ethereum, geth

Following this read to retrieve event logs from my contract:
https://goethereumbook.org/event-read

When I loop over the logs like below, I'm getting empty vlog.Data that triggers the error:

abi: attempting to unmarshall an empty string while arguments are expected

```
for _, vlog := range logs
```

However, len(logs) shows that there are events, and I can still get some info such as vlog.Topics. Is there any way to fix this or an alternative solution to retrieve event logs?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the first iteration of looping over the logs is empty for some reason, I was able to solve it just by continuing on to the next iteration.